# How to know that we scrolled ScrollView to top

Tags: android, kotlin

I have some fragment, NestedScrollView is root layout in it. What I want is to scroll at middle of this fragment, then press some ACTION_BUTTON which must trigger autoscroll to top of fragment and invoking some action, but only after the fragment (NestedScrolView) rich top (for smooth animations).

I write this function:

```
fun NestedScrollView.scrollTop(callback: () -> Unit) {

    setOnScrollChangeListener { _: NestedScrollView?, _: Int, scrollY: Int, _: Int, _: Int ->

        if (scrollY == 0) {

            callback.invoke()
        }
    }

    fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP)
}
```

but it doesn't work if I press ACTION_BUTTON when fragment is already at top.

And also, I get some blink for a second before callback is being invoke.

So, what is the best way to handle click at ACTION_BUTTON in my case? Is there functions for NestedScrollView with callbacks, invoking after reaching top and how to handle situation when I am already at the top of screen (and OnScrollChangeListener doesn't calls)?

Answer (score 0):

```
scrollView.viewTreeObserver.addOnScrollChangedListener {
    if (!scrollView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
        // Bottom of scroll view.
    }
    if (!scrollView.canScrollVertically(-1)) {
        // Top of scroll view.
    }
}
```